# Unity 5.5: Mesh Intersection to be rendered invisible with shader? (Pictures)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, intersection, mesh, invisible

I'm trying to make a single shader that checks if it has collided with a mesh (with the same shader), if it has, then it should not render that collided part at all. For both meshes.

I'm trying to get this effect:
[image: The white area is the "invisible" area that I want]

I have used a crosssection shader to achieve this but it's not what I want:
[image: I get the intersected area as colored]

This is the shader code:

```
    // Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'glstate.matrix.invtrans.modelview[0]' with 'UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV'
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'glstate.matrix.mvp' with 'UNITY_MATRIX_MVP'

// 2 Pass Edition

Shader "cross_section_v004a"
{
    Properties 
    {
        section_depth ("section depth (x, y, z, depth)", vector) = (0,0,0,0.15)
        section_color ("section color", color) = (0.5,0.1, 0.1, 1)

        color_map ("color map", 2D) = "white" {}

    }   
    SubShader 
    {   
        Pass
        {           
            CULL OFF

CGPROGRAM //--------------
//#pragma target 3.0
#pragma vertex   vertex_shader
#pragma fragment fragment_shader

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform float4 section_depth;
uniform float4 section_color;
uniform sampler2D color_map;    

float4x4 rotate(float3 r) 
{ 
    float3 c, s; 
    sincos(r.x, s.x, c.x); 
    sincos(r.y, s.y, c.y); 
    sincos(r.z, s.z, c.z);
    return float4x4( c.y*c.z,    -s.z,     s.y, 0, 
                         s.z, c.x*c.z,    -s.x, 0, 
                        -s.y,     s.x, c.x*c.y, 0, 
                           0,       0,       0, 1 );
} 

struct a2v 
{
    float4 vertex   : POSITION;
    float4 color    : COLOR;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;                                
    float4 normal   : TEXCOORD1; 
    float4 vertex   : TEXCOORD2;
    float4 mask     : TEXCOORD3;                
};

v2f vertex_shader( a2v IN )
{                                                   
    v2f OUT;

    float4x4 r   = rotate(radians(section_depth.xyz) +_SinTime.xyz);
    float4 c     = float4(IN.vertex.xyz,1);

    OUT.mask     = mul(r, c);
    OUT.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
    OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;

    r *= float4x4(   1,-1,-1, 0,
                    -1, 1,-1, 0,
                    -1,-1, 1, 0,
                     0, 0, 0, 1 ); // the section_depth.xyz need to be inverted !

    OUT.normal   = mul(r, float4(1,0,0,1));
    OUT.vertex   = IN.vertex;

    return OUT;
}

void fragment_shader(   v2f IN,
                        out float4 finalcolor : COLOR)  

{
    if(IN.mask.x > section_depth.w)
        discard;

    float3 N = IN.normal.xyz;

    N = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, float4(N, 1));              
    //float diffuse = saturate(dot(glstate.light[0].position, N));  

    finalcolor = float4(0,0,0,1);                               
    finalcolor.xyz = section_color *(0.6 +0.4);
}
ENDCG //--------------

        } // Pass

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Pass
        {           
            CULL BACK

CGPROGRAM //--------------
#pragma vertex   vertex_shader
#pragma fragment fragment_shader

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

uniform float4 section_depth;
uniform float4 section_color;
uniform sampler2D color_map;    

float4x4 rotate(float3 r) 
{ 
    float3 c, s; 
    sincos(r.x, s.x, c.x); 
    sincos(r.y, s.y, c.y); 
    sincos(r.z, s.z, c.z);
    return float4x4( c.y*c.z,    -s.z,     s.y, 0, 
                         s.z, c.x*c.z,    -s.x, 0, 
                        -s.y,     s.x, c.x*c.y, 0, 
                           0,       0,       0, 1 );
} 

struct a2v 
{
    float4 vertex   : POSITION;
    float4 color    : COLOR;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;                                
    float3 normal   : TEXCOORD1; 
    float4 vertex   : TEXCOORD2;
    float4 mask     : TEXCOORD3;                
};

v2f vertex_shader( a2v IN )
{                                                   
    v2f OUT;

    float4x4 r   = rotate(radians(section_depth.xyz) +_SinTime.xyz);
    float4 c     = float4(IN.vertex.xyz,1);

    OUT.mask     = mul(r, c);
    OUT.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
    OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
    OUT.normal   = IN.normal;
    OUT.vertex   = IN.vertex;

    return OUT;
}

void fragment_shader(   v2f IN,
                        out float4 finalcolor : COLOR)  

{
    if(IN.mask.x > section_depth.w)
        discard;

    float3 N = IN.normal;

    N = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, float4(N, 1));              
    //float diffuse = saturate(dot(glstate.light[0].position, N));

    finalcolor = float4(0,0,0,1);                                           
    finalcolor.xyz = tex2D(color_map, IN.texcoord).xyz *(0.6 +0.4);
}
ENDCG //--------------

        } // Pass

    } // SubShader
} // Shader
```

However, the rest of the object should be visible, I mean to say that I don't want the parts that are NOT getting intersected to be invisible (when viewed from the invisible parts) so Stencil shaders won't or aren't doing the trick. Something like this:
[image]

I want to know what is the correct way to approach to this problem. I'm fairly new to shader programming and I don't know to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Well...there's a problem here. In your last picture you say you want them to overlap like that. Except...there's no way to do that with shaders. That dark-gray surface where the one cube is "sliced" off doesn't exist. And there's no way to create it using any shader. You're trying to create [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) without manipulating the mesh objects themseslves and that just isn't possible.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I want them to overlap/intersect like that. The parts that are getting intersected don't have to be rendered. This can't be achieved with shaders?

Comment: The effect without rendering the internal surface would look much different. I'm not sure how I'd go about doing it though, try finding an intersection shader, that might help. (An intersection shader renders solid when the point is "near" other objects).